# Crashlytics fails to build a custom Android flavor with sourceSets and no res folder in main

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Trying to use Crashlytics on my Android project while using sourceSets with a custom Flavor.  I do not have a res folder in my main folder.

Here's my project structure:

```
app
--src
----main
------AndroidMainfest.xml
------java
--custom_res_dir
```

Here's the relevant poritions of my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ....
    productFlavors {
        customflavor {
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        customflavor {
            res.srcDirs += ['custom_res_dir']
        }
    }
}
```

A link to a sample Android project that can generate the issue:
https://github.com/sgallese/CrashlyticsAppWithoutResFolder

And the build failure that occurs when running

```
$ ./gradlew :app:fabricGenerateResourcesCustomflavorDebug --stacktrace

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
Crashlytics couldn't find the res folder specified in sourceSets.main.res, please make one. It picked: src/main/res
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.leftShift(AbstractTask.java:513)
        at org.gradle.api.Task$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.pluginGenerateResources(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:114)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$pluginGenerateResources.call(Unknown Source)
        at 
....
....
....
com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.StandardAndroidProjectFactory.create(StandardAndroidProjectFactory.java:93)
            at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:483)
        ... 113 more
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesCustomflavorDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesCustomflavorDebug'.
> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesCustomflavorDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:346)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.this$2$callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$_pluginGenerateResources_closure4.doCall(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:596)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:577)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$1.execute(TaskMutator.java:90)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$1.execute(TaskMutator.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.PluginException: Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:356)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.gradleMain(DeveloperTools.java:292)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:330)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics could not parse the Android Project structure.
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:488)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid resource path: /Users/sebastian/CrashlyticsAppWithoutResFolder/app/src/main/res
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.StandardAndroidProject.getValuesDirectory(StandardAndroidProject.java:53)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.StandardAndroidProjectFactory.createTypedProject(StandardAndroidProjectFactory.java:168)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.StandardAndroidProjectFactory.create(StandardAndroidProjectFactory.java:118)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.StandardAndroidProjectFactory.create(StandardAndroidProjectFactory.java:93)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:483)
        ... 81 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.873 secs
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I got your email as well and am trying to see if we have a supported way of doing this.

Comment: +Mike Bonnell, BTW, when are you going to fix the `Task.leftShift(Closure)` warning? It should have to be a quick update like [this one](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release/pull/204/files). Thanks.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I would be really glad too if the leftShift warning would finally get away!! I just tried with the latest version of crashlytics android dependency and it is still warning about it :(

Comment: @Xexiz and thelawnmoweman - 1.22.2 of the Fabric Gradle plugin has the fix ; it was released May 31st https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
I'd refresh your dependencies or update the value you're using if you still see the issue.

Comment: Awesome @MikeBonnell :) Did you just put it up on the website? I checked yesterday and updated to 1.22.1 or perhaps I was blind and never saw 1.22.2 :) Anyhow, thanks, just tried and it is now clean!!

Comment: There was a delay in getting the release notes live. The fix was live, but the notes weren't.

Comment: did you able to solve this ?

Comment: @MohamedALOUANE yes this is resolved in the above comment by  Mike Bonnell, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882727/crashlytics-fails-to-build-a-custom-android-flavor-with-sourcesets-and-no-res-fo#comment75876289_43882727